# How to prevent giving the book to the user if he has a debt (simply put, if the value is 0 or less)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC.

I'm trying to prevent the creation of a new record if a particular user is a debtor, but I don't know how to implement it. I need the record not to be created for a specific user if he is a debtor and the value is 0 or less as shown in the picture below

[image: screenshot]

According to my logic, I've tried to do the following:

```
                if (orders.DateOrder.Day <= DateTime.Now.Day)
                {
                    ViewBag.err = "This user is a critical debtor!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }
```

But it doesn't work that way. It is necessary to prevent the creation of a record for a specific user, but I do not know how to do it. How could i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the picture there is no value 0 or less ??

Comment: And I think there is an error. If "now" is May, 4th and `orders.DateOrder` is April, 28th, then your condition will evaluate to false. Is that as expected?

Comment: @mjwills I'm trying to prevent giving a book to a particular user if the value of "Days left" is zero or less. But with this conditional statement, I do not forbid giving the book to the debtor (that's what i need to do), but only limit the date (prohibiting the creation of a record if the date is equal to or less than today).Hope I made it very clear

Comment: @Fildor Yes, there is no value equal to zero or less in the picture. If there were, they would have a value of 0 or -1, for example.

Comment: Obviously, @Dimitry49921. So that's intentional. Ok. But still, I am having a hard time to understand what your problem actually is. If you ask me, you simply need a roundtrip to your user DB and check debt status. This can be ok or not , done. And your "limiting condition" is also broken. You only check "Day **in month**".

Comment: @Dimitry49921 please use the [edit] link to add information to your question.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

In creation method, before code that CREATES record you need to check if user meets certain requirements (In your case: if your user is a debtor.). You can get into like this:

Mark creation method as bool return type. Then inside that method, before code that creates record check if user is valid and if is not emit some kind of event like "userNotValidEvent" and then return false. In all other cases just add user and return true.

With that emited event you can listen to it in your controller, and whenever event occurs, just show information that user can't borrow a book.

Comment: Why do you need an event for that? This is a simple validation. No events needed.

Comment: I do not know. This is how i would did that.

Comment: Remember we are talking ASP MVC here. So, such an event won't be a good fit. (Did not dv, btw)

Comment: Can you explain more? (Or give some kind of source?) :).

Comment: How to check if user is valid? I just don't know exactly how to write a condition that will check the validity of the user.